# Plotting lon/lat point (without manual conversion) on XY map using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, reprojection-mathematics, plotting

I am data scientist not experienced in GIS and need to do some simple map plotting of the Netherlands. Using Geopandas everything works out nice and dandy for my purposes however I am stuck on 1 aspect:

The map I drew has the following CRS:

map_df__.crs
{'init': 'epsg:28992'} (this is what NL looks like to de dutch native)

[image: plain image of the Netherlands]

I want to plot a couple of points of which I get the lon/lat coordinates from Google Maps.

Muddling my way to understand projections on the fly I got to this code:

```
map_df.to_crs(epsg=4289).plot(edgecolor='black')
```

Which gives this map: (Red dot: Amsterdam is an example)

[image: squased map]

To a Dutch person this map looks a bit squashed. I am guessing because because of the projection.

How do I plot a lon/lat point (without manual conversion) on an XY map i.e. how can make the squashed map look like the 'stretched' version?

---

The suggested espg:
map_df.to_crs(epsg=3857).plot(edgecolor='black'), gives:

[image: suggested eps 3857]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but a popular projection is Web Mercator.  Try EPSG:3857 to see if that looks more of what you'd expect.

Comment: Web Mercator is highly distorted as far north as the Netherlands.

Comment: It appears the part you are missing is the need to reproject your decimal degrees point into your preferred coordinate reference for mapping. Yes, a *Plate Carrée* of geographic 4289 will look squashed, because it's Plate Carrée. In order for your point to align with any other coordsys, it must be projected into that coordsys.

Comment: Please make sure Gerardus Mercator's birthplace is properly projected.

Comment: Search here or on Google using geopandas reproject. That should turn up several examples.

Comment: I would put your point in a geodataframe and use the reprojection support built into GeoPandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put your point in a geodataframe and use the reprojection support built into geopandas.

That looks like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas

final_crs = {'init': 'epsg:28992'}
NL = (
    geopandas.read_file('nl_1km.shp')
        .to_crs(final_crs)
)

# note: always give `Point` x and then the y coord
amsterdamish = Point((4.9, 52.4))
gdf_am = geopandas.GeoSeries([amsterdamish], crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(6.5, 6.5))
NL.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='0.35')
gdf_am.to_crs(final_crs).plot(ax=ax)
```

And I get:

[image]

---

NB: my NL dataset is weird, but it came from here: https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/netherlands-shapefile

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak pandas, but:

> map_df__.crs {'init': 'epsg:28992'}

likely tells it to map a dataframe, using the CRS (coordinate reference system) of a certain number (28992); which I looked up here: https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/

Looking at your code, I do not see anything which adds a dot to the map.

[EPSG stands for European Petroleum Survey Group. They publish a database of coordinate system information plus some very good related documents on map projections and datums.](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002814)